# CSS3 div background-image autoresize

Tags: css, background-image

I was looking for many posts here on stackoverflow, but there was nothing, what could help me. Maybe this question is trivial, but i don't know how to do that, because I am beginner in this

So i have some header, where is logo, menu and some title -that is not problem. Under this header i have div with class slider, where i want to have some background-image and on this background-image i want to have some button and title and another image. And here is finally my question.

**What should i do, if i want to have this background-image of this div on full width and with auto height (height from end of header to end of screen) for any screen resolution on desktop?**

I mean: if i have resolution 1920x1080 i want to have this bg-image from end of header to end of screen. Same thing for resolution for example 1366x768 etc etc...i hope you understand my question.

Example on this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb3Vp.png)

**Header is red. And i want to have bg-image (in this case white part of image, but i want to have image there) auto resize for any screen resolution.**

I really hope you understand my question and someone can help me.

Really thanks for any reply

http://jsfiddle.net/YKY4t/

I have some errors in code so please...

Code:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300,700);

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.mainheader {
width: 100%;
height: 10%;
background-color: #ff5959;
position: absolute;
}
.mainheader img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-top: 1.5%;
float: left;
}
.title {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 22%;
font-size: 35px;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}
.meta {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 18%;
margin-top: 3%;
font-size: 19px;
font-family: 'Quicksand',sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff;
}
.nav {
position: absolute;
right: 20%;
margin-top: 1%;
font-size: 19px;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.nav li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
}
.nav li a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
margin-left: 25%;
}
.slider img {
background-image: url(../img/slider-image.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Use media queries for different screens resolution: @media all and (min-width: /* min resolution to show this background*/) {  /* Your CSS code */}

Answer (score 0):

As i commented, you can use media queries for the different screen sizes where you can use different resolution images. In that case:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1920) {
    .img-holder img{
        background-img: url(../img/slider-image.png);
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1366) {
    .img-holder img{
        background-img: url(../img/slider-image-medium.png);
    }
}
```

You can use them to use all screen resolutions you want to cover.
You alse can use any responsive framework like Bootstrap which responsives the images.